# Am I facing floating point issue?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

Let's say `f(x) = (4x^2-9)/(2x-3)`. The function `f(x)` is undefined at `x=3/2`. Note that the function can be factored to yield `f(x)=2x+3` but let's examine the first equation. In the following script when `x=1.5`, the function `f(x=1.5)=4.0`

```
clear all
clc

x = 0:0.3:2;

for i = 1:length(x)
if x(i) == 1.5  % this line for some reasons is ignored. 
    y(i) = 6;
else
    y(i) = (4*x(i)^2-9)/(2*x(i)-3);
end
end
x
y
```

The output of the preceding script is

```
x = 0         0.3000    0.6000    0.9000    1.2000    1.5000    1.8000
y = 3.0000    3.6000    4.2000    4.8000    5.4000    4.0000    6.6000
```

Why `y=4.0000` when `x=1.5000`? Now let's run the code without for-loop,

```
clear all
clc
x = 0:0.3:2
y = (4*x.^2-9)/(2*x-3)
```

The result of the above code is

```
x = 0       0.3000    0.6000    0.9000    1.2000    1.5000    1.8000
y = 3.6000
```

There is only one value for `f(x)`. Can any one explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question, yes, you are running into a floating point precision error. You can check this by checking the difference between the `x` value that it's supposed to be a 1.5 and a 1.5.

```
x(6)-1.5

%ans=
%     -2.2204e-16
```

Specifically in your case it comes from using 0.3 to construct the vector `x` since that value cannot be precisely saved into binary, [see here for a deeper explanation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57444-faq-why-is-0-3-0-2-0-1-not-equal-to-zero)

Any of the following should solve your problem

```
x=0:3:20;      %Create the vector based on values that can be represented
x=x/10;

x=[0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8]; %Directly input the values

abs(x(i)-1.5) < tol  %Instead of directly comparing values, compare the difference to a determined tolerance (very small compared to the values at hand)
```

As for your second question @Phill already gave you the answer, you are using `/` matrix division, and you want `./` element wise division.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your first example with the for loop in Octave, I do not see a problem with the x=1.5 if statement being ignored. Perhaps this is a subtle difference between Matlab and Octave for this although I would be surprised.

For the array notation second example

```
clear all
clc
x = 0:0.3:2
y = (4*x.^2-9)/(2*x-3)
```

You have chosen the [matrix division operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) `/` instead of the [element by element division operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) `./`